# C# - Update UI on Timer tick while delaying based on Timer value

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I want my WPF application to display a 3-second countdown before displaying an image, using a timer to display the "3, 2, 1" count based on the elapsed three seconds (meaning use the timer to update the UI) while waiting to display the image until the three seconds have elapsed (meaning have the method wait).

In pseudocode, I am trying to do the following:

- 3 is displayed, then one second elapses
- 2 is displayed, then one second elapses
- 1 is displayed, then one second elapses
- The image is displayed

I am trying to use a System.Timers.Timer, such as:

```
...

public int Countdown = 3;

...

private void UpdateCountdown(object source, EventArgs e) 
{
    Countdown--;
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += UpdateCountdown;
    timer.Start();

    while (Countdown > 0)
    {
        // do not act until the 3 seconds have elapsed
    }

    // now that 3 seconds have elapsed...
    ShowImage();
}
```

and in my xaml, I am binding the Countdown value to a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Name="TbCountdown" Text="{Binding Path=Countdown}"/>
```

I have tried a few different things, such as trying Dispatcher.Invoke. My problem is that one of the two following things always happens:

1. The UI gets blocked and does not show 3 turn into 2, etc.
2. The UI shows the 3, 2, 1 correctly but the ShowImage() method does not wait for the 3 seconds, it just happens instantly.

Any advice?

Comment: Why dont you use ajax and Jquery ?

Comment: ONce the time is complete call ajax method and display image on div or where ever you want to show

Comment: @nikunjMnage What does Ajax and jQuery have to do with a desktop WPF application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't busy spin on the `Countdown` value in `DoStuff`, rather put the test and `ShowImage()` in the `UpdateCountdown` handler.

```
private void UpdateCountdown(object source, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (--Countdown == 0)
        ShowImage();
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += UpdateCountdown;
    timer.Start();    
}
```